# How do I connect from a docker container to my localhost (windows machine that runs Docker toolbox)?

Tags: docker

I have a windows machine that has docker toolbox installed. I have spanned virtual box (linux). Inside of it I am running .Net Core app in a docker container.

I can access the .Net Core api by calling from windows browser http://192.168.99.100:3000

but I also installed Jira on windows. Jira app is accessible from windows on http://localhost:8080.  I have a webhook configured in JIRA app that needs to call .Net Core API which is running on virtualbox in a container. webhook is making REST call to .Net Core app running in docker http://192.168.99.100:3000/api/Account but Jira is not reaching it and webhook is not firing.

Also the API that runs in docker container needs to do the rest  callback back to JIRA which is running on physical windows machine. How do I make this to and from communication work?

Do I need to use NAT on virtualbox to provide some sort of mapping? Can you please be specific about this I have spent 2 days trying to make it work. Thank you

$ docker build -t webapisample .
$ docker run -d -p 3000:80 --name myapp webapisample
edd8f29e250115919000cc389ebbcbe8c9574a6aab90592cc67c44ffc6d67343

Answer (score 0):

My answer might only partially help you but here it is. From inside docker container, you access your local machine using 'host.docker.internal' so if you want to access JIRA from inside your .NET Core app container you can try calling 'http://host.docker.internal:8080' instead of 'http://localhost:8080'.